# How can multiple buffering make program faster

Tags: opengl, framebuffer, shader-storage-buffer

I have some question on multiple buffering in OpenGL. For example, I have a program. It does following things:

1. do a depth pre-pass, and write some information on the shader storage buffer.
2. use the data on the shader storage buffer draw something on the default framebuffer and swap the buffer, so I can see the picture

Since I only create one shader storage buffer. GPU can't do the next framebuffer's step 1 'do a depth pre-pass', until the last framebuffer finished step 2 'use the data on the shader storage buffer'.

Is it true? How can I use shader storage buffer effective, when GPU is using multi buffering(suppose I have enought memory on GPU).

Comment: "Since I only create one shader storage buffer. GPU can't do the next framebuffer's step 1 'do a depth pre-pass', until the last framebuffer finished step 2". That is not true, the GL does not make any such guarantees. What the driver can do under the hood is totally unrestricted, and using several differtent storages for a single GL object is not completely impossible. The easy way to hint the driver that you actually want that would be by explicitely [_orphaning_](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming#Buffer_update) the buffer object between the iterations.

Comment: However, in your specific scenario, the issue is not implicit synchronization between the CPU and GPU. It is just the synchronization between the draw call of the last iteration and another draw call of the current iteration, and you have a framebuffer swap inbetween, which typically means a change in render target, so the pipeline is flushed most likely anyway, so there is nothing to worry about at all. The GPU is _not_ rendering multiple frames in parallel. The GPU driver is queuing up work - potentially for more than one frame, and the GPU might be queuing up several rendered frames.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood the render pipeline of OpenGL. Thank you very much and Happy new year.